# Text below RadioButtons

Tags: android, android-layout

I need your help to solve my layout problem.. I have 4 RadioButtons, they appear as usual in this scheme:

> O text1   O text2   O text3   O text4

where O is the button.. I would know if it's possible to change this layout in this way:

> O        O       O       O
>
> text1  text2  text3  text4

Comment: Please check below the modern answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/69093063/5730321

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think the plain RadioButton widget can do that by default. You'll need to do one of a few things to achieve that effect. You can create your own RadioButton view class by combining a RadioButton and a TextView so that you have complete control over where the items are in relation to each other. Or you can skip making it a view and just use two elements in your layout, 1 TextView and one RadioButton(with no text set to it).

Answer (score 36):

This is the solution to set the Text below RadioButtons:

This code `android:drawablePadding="-20dp"` is not needed.

You add your own selector drawable here: android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_Image_Here".

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/RadioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Icon1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_Image_Here"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/your_Text_Here"
            android:textColor="@color/icons_color" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Icon2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_Image_Here"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/your_Text_Here"
            android:textColor="@color/icons_color" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: but regarding to your solution, what's the benefit of creating a RadioGroup with a RadioButtons inside it? , I mean if I set the RadioButton to checked during the run-time it won't change anything and to make a visible change I have to change drawableTop, which means I don't need to create RadioGroup , all I need is a regular Hor Layout contains a number of Ver Layouts each with ImageView and TextView.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat your solution will cost more

Comment: well, more cache? more time?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat more drawing and layout time

Comment: Does it really work with a selectable drawable ? (meaning that it's pressed state will change for instance)

Comment: it works perfectly with selector! If you set selector as drawableTop it changes drawables automatically! So it is a perfect sollution!

Comment: android:button="@null"   is a better than android:button="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: It is quite easier than create a custom class by extending Built-in RadioButton Class.

Comment: @ParthPatel an answer would be +1 (on the answer of course)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution with default RadioButton:

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/radio7"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tvDays7"
          android:text="7 looong days"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_below="@id/radio7"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: that seems to make the radiogroup no longer select one only. Was there something else you did to not break the functionality of a radiogroup?

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file:

```
<!--...-->

<RadioGroup
    android:checkedButton="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupBase"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        
        <RadioButton
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        
        <TextView
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="@string/textView1_Text"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        
    </LinearLayout>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        
        <RadioButton
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        
        <TextView
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="@string/textView2_Text"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        
    </LinearLayout>
    
    <!--more RadioButtons-->

</RadioGroup>

<!--...-->
```

Set up `onClick()` listeners for the `LinearLayout`s (**not for `RadioButton`s**) in the `onCreate()` procedure (don't forget to `import android.view.View;` and `import android.widget.RadioGroup;`):

```
//...

findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(final View objView)
    {
        ((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupBase)).check(findViewById(R.id.radioButton1).getId());
    }
});

findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(final View objView)
    {
        ((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupBase)).check(findViewById(R.id.radioButton2).getId());
    }
});

//more SetOnClickListener() calls for more LinearLayouts ("RadioButtons")

//...
```

All that's left is to set up an `onCheckedChanged()` listener for the `RadioGroup` in the same `onCreate()` procedure:

```
//...

((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupBase)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(final RadioGroup objRadioGroup, final int nCheckedID)
    {
        if (!objRadioGroup.isShown())
            return;
        
        //do something depending on which RadioButton was checked
    }
});

//...
```

It might be a good idea to make a simple getter for the `RadioGroup` and maybe for the `LinearLayout`s as well (the latter would require `import android.widget.LinearLayout;`):

```
//...

private RadioGroup Get_radioGroupBase() { return findViewById(R.id.radioGroupBase); }
private LinearLayout Get_linearLayout1() { return findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1); }
private LinearLayout Get_linearLayout2() { return findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2); }
//more getters for more LinearLayouts ("RadioButtons")

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, radio button text positioning can easily be adjusted with MaterialRadioButton.

[image: Radio button with text below]

```
<com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rbThemeLight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/rb_selector"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:text="@string/settings_theme_light" />
```

A few notes here:

1. With `android:button="@null"` you disable the default radio button drawable.
2. You set a custom drawable with `android:drawableTop`
   There are other options available, sich as `drawableTop`, `drawableEnd` etc.

For the drawable you may use something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/colorWs" />
            <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="1.5dp" android:color="@color/colorClay" />
            <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

It works either with and without a RadioGroup.